# What is the best messaging server for communicating across java and .net?

Tags: c#, jboss

We've been using [jbossmq](http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-10525) and [csil](http://csil.sourceforge.net). The implementation has been successful in production for 6 years, but I'm wondering if something better is available.

One issue is jbossmq's thread per client model, and scheduled end of life. Another is csil's lack of support for JBossMessaging, which is the latest JMS implementation from JBoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IKVM for compiling .NET from Java looks interesting.

For .NET messaging check out [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at an ActiveMQ backend with NMS clients.  I've had no problems with it. 
I can't vouch for it though because the production system I am using it in is not high volume.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). It is a compiler that generates .NET assemblies from java byte code (jars). We have had good success, stability and performance using native JBoss assemblies created by IKVM and we've implemented the usual client side protocol (RMI, JMS, EJB) although, not actually the new JBossMessaging. At any rate, implementing this approach, you can pick which ever remoting protocol suits you best with less worries about compatibility,

//Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source intraprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look into IceWarp.  You can download a free trial and see how it works for you.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55914/169404